# Magento : Paypal Website Payments Standard, redirect issue

Tags: paypal

I recently encountered with a weird paypal redirect issue. this issue comes when i select `Paypal Website Standard` as payment method and place order. here after clicking on Place Order ideally it should have redirect me to paypal's website for payment processing but it gets stuck on `domain.com/paypal/standard/redirect/` giving me a blank screen without any error.

If i hit the same URL on other magento site than it gives me these error `Fatal error: Call to a member function validate() on a non-object in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php on line 137`. but for these site case is completely different.

Below is the Action's code and in that these line `$this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypal/standard_redirect')->toHtml());` is not getting executed.

```
   /**
     * When a customer chooses Paypal on Checkout/Payment page
     *
     */
    public function redirectAction()
    {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $session->setPaypalStandardQuoteId($session->getQuoteId());
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypal/standard_redirect')->toHtml());
        $session->unsQuoteId();
        $session->unsRedirectUrl();
    }
```

Guys please help.

**[EDIT]**

if i do below changes than it will work

```
//Mage_Paypal_StandardController
$this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypal/standard_redirect')->toHtml());
to
$this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypal/standard_redirect')->_toHtml());

//Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Redirect
protected function _toHtml()
to
public function _toHtml()
```

but i dont think it is good to mess with the access modifier of the method.

Comment: I am having the same issue when I upgraded Magento 1.5 to 1.9. Issue occurs when you register at checkout and buy downloadable products. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

The solution you've added isn't a solution. First of all, it's a core hack, which are not the way to go. Also, `_toHtml()` and `toHtml()` look the same, but do two completely different things. Looking at the method in the latest version of Magento, this is what both methods do:

**toHtml()**

```
final public function toHtml()
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abstract_to_html_before', array('block' => $this));
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output/' . $this->getModuleName())) {
        return '';
    }
    $html = $this->_loadCache();
    if ($html === false) {
        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        /** @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
        if ($this->hasData('translate_inline')) {
            $translate->setTranslateInline($this->getData('translate_inline'));
        }

        $this->_beforeToHtml();
        $html = $this->_toHtml();
        $this->_saveCache($html);

        if ($this->hasData('translate_inline')) {
            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
        }
    }
    $html = $this->_afterToHtml($html);

    /**
     * Check framing options
     */
    if ($this->_frameOpenTag) {
        $html = '<' . $this->_frameOpenTag . '>' . $html . '<' . $this->_frameCloseTag . '>';
    }

    /**
     * Use single transport object instance for all blocks
     */
    if (self::$_transportObject === null) {
        self::$_transportObject = new Varien_Object;
    }
    self::$_transportObject->setHtml($html);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abstract_to_html_after',
        array('block' => $this, 'transport' => self::$_transportObject));
    $html = self::$_transportObject->getHtml();

    return $html;
}
```

**_toHtml()**

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $standard = Mage::getModel('paypal/standard');

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $form->setAction($standard->getConfig()->getPaypalUrl())
        ->setId('paypal_standard_checkout')
        ->setName('paypal_standard_checkout')
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->setUseContainer(true);
    foreach ($standard->getStandardCheckoutFormFields() as $field=>$value) {
        $form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$value));
    }
    $idSuffix = Mage::helper('core')->uniqHash();
    $submitButton = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Submit(array(
        'value'    => $this->__('Click here if you are not redirected within 10 seconds...'),
    ));
    $id = "submit_to_paypal_button_{$idSuffix}";
    $submitButton->setId($id);
    $form->addElement($submitButton);
    $html = '<html><body>';
    $html.= $this->__('You will be redirected to the PayPal website in a few seconds.');
    $html.= $form->toHtml();
    $html.= '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("paypal_standard_checkout").submit();</script>';
    $html.= '</body></html>';

    return $html;
}
```

As you can see, the `toHtml()` calls `_toHtml()`, but also does a lot more. Since you now know that the issue is not in the `_toHtml()` method, you should check the other functionality in the `toHtml()`. One of the things we can see here, is that it dispatches two events: one before and one after the code is executed. Also, there is a check if the extension is enabled or not and it does a check on the cache.

So, if you check if there is any extension using the events in the method, that would give you a little more information. Also, a really good way to debug this, is by using Xdebug.

I know this doesn't solve the problem, but this might explain the stuff that's done.